# How to put built in pagination control on top and bottom of Angular UI Grid 3

Tags: pagination, angular-ui-grid

Is there a solution to put same **built in** pagination control on **top and bottom** of Angular UI Grid 3.x?

I know that solution is build own control like demonstrated [on example](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination)